# Value Error: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

I want to call a function in order to load a dataset but I'm getting an error:  ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Can someone help me please?

```
def loadMyDataset(path):
    my_data=[]
    f = open(path , "r")
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        my_strings = line.split("\t")
        my_data.append([float(my_strings[0]),float(my_strings[1])])
    return my_data        

myDataFile = 'g-dss4.txt'
data_size=10

my_dataSet= loadMyDataset(myDataFile)
print("Συνολο δεδομενων:", my_dataSet)
```

Comment: You should add a print line after you `line.split("\t")` to see what `my_strings`  contain. The error is quite clear, you are trying to convert something to a float that isn't float like.

Comment: It's impossible to say what the problem is without knowing what value of `my_strings` causes the error. It would appear you don' have two tab-separated `float` literals in the line.

Comment: what does `my_strings` look like?

Comment: You've also cut off the end of the error message from the exception, which would tell us exactly *which* string triggered the `ValueError`. (Unless that *is* the exact error message, in which case it would appear that `my_strings[1]` is an empty string.)

Comment: As a side note, `float` ignores whitespaces. Stripping is not necessary.

Comment: If you want to try reading floats from this file, line by line, and report failures, use `try` and `except`. You can read a bit more on that here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Please post (some of) your 'g-dss4.txt' file.

Comment: This is how my g-dss4.txt file looks like: 2 8
1 4
1 2
5 4
1 9
7 3
7 1
8 0
7 6
1 0